# The $divide accumulator is a unary operator

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I created a request to Mongo DB:

```
{
    $project:
      {
        difference:
          {
            $subtract: ['$' + endDate, '$' + startDate]
          }
      }
  },
  {
    $match:
      {
        difference:
          {
            $gte: 0
          }
      }
  },
  {
    $group:
      {
        _id: null,
        avgTime:
          {
            $divide:
              [
                {
                  $avg: "$difference"
                }, 60000 // in minutes
              ]
          }
      }
  }
```

I try to:

1. Calculate difference between end date and start date and take it
   where this `difference` > 0
2. Calculate average value
3. Devide it on 60000 (to get minutes)

But I got the error: **The `$divide` accumulator is a unary operator**

How can I fix this request?

Comment: You cannot use `$divide` with `$group` stage. It must be the `$group` accumulator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *But I got the error: The $divide accumulator is a unary operator*

The `<accumulator>` operator must be one of the following accumulator operators: [accumulator-operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#accumulator-operator), and `$divide` operator is not one of them,

The `$avg` operator must be in root if you want to average,

Correct your syntax in `$group` stage and add new stage to get `$divide`

```
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      avgTime: { $avg: "$difference" }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      avgTime: { $divide: ["$avgTime", 60000] }
    }
  }
```